# Why are my fonts not changing?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Snell Roundhand Script';
src: url('../fonts/snell-roundhand-script.eot');
src: url('../fonts/snell-roundhand-script.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/snell-roundhand-script.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/snell-roundhand-script.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/snell-roundhand-script.svg#Snell Roundhand Script') format('svg');
}
@font-face {
font-family: 'Baskerville Old Face';
src: url('../fonts/ufonts.com_baskerville-old-face.eot');
src: url('../fonts/ufonts.com_baskerville-old-face.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/ufonts.com_baskerville-old-face.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/ufonts.com_baskerville-old-face.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/ufonts.com_baskerville-old-face.svg#Baskerville Old Face') format('svg');
}
```

The above code is the font-face code

And below i am poting the css i have added:

```
.big-red-text{
color: #ff0000;
font-family: Snell Roundhand Script;
font-size: 50px;
text-align: center;
}

.big-orange-text{
color: #ff6600;
text-align: center;
font-weight: 600;
font-family: Baskerville Old Face;

}
```

Is there something missing in this? For it not to take the font into consideration? All the fonts are stored in the font folder in the root directory.

Comment: style stored in .css file and cache problems?

Answer (score 2):

If your font name contains spaces, you have to enclosure it in single quotes. 
Without spaces in the name you can lose the single quotes but I suggest to always use them to avoid mistakes.

So as Fundhor suggests it will work with

```
font-family: 'Snell Roundhand Script';
```

and

```
font-family: 'Baskerville Old Face';
```

Make sure your files are in the right place:

```
- css
-- fonts.css <-- here you are declaring your @font-face
- fonts
-- snell-roundhand-script.eot
-- etc...
```

Additionally include your `fonts.css` before you are using the `font-family`

Comment: wrapping the font-family in single quotes doesn't help it

Comment: To make it easier to debug, try with names that do not contain spaces.

Comment: still nothing, i change it from snell roundhand script to just snell and same with baskerville old face to baskerville

Comment: Can you check if your css file where you declare your fonts is at the right place? it has to be directly in a folder (maybe 'css') in your root directory. E.g. /css/fonts.css

Comment: i tried putting the fonts in the root in the css folder making a fonts folder in the css folder, still nothing

Comment: Can you _exactly_ describe your file structure in your question? Including all file names.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this :

```
.big-red-text{
    color: #ff0000;
    font-family: 'Snell Roundhand Script';
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: wrapping the font-family in single quotes doesn't help it

Answer (score 0):

Did you purchase the font or font-family?

Url:https://www.fonts.com/font/linotype/snell-roundhand

The support team at fonts.com should be able to resolve your issue.